# CSS Positioning: Same width in percent, but one div seems to get smaller

Tags: html, css, css-position

So I have a problem and hope you could help me out here for I am out of ideas:

I try to create a html/css-based bill of fare (I hope it's right... perhaps "menu" is better english? sry, german here), and it worked out fine so far, but there's one little flaw in my css I cant' figure out.

To make things clearer, I created a fiddle over here: [removed, the picture makes it clear :) ]

So in the fiddle you see the "days"-line, which css-class `.day` have just the same percentual width than my menu-cssclass.

Here's the corresponding css:

```
.a4 .days td div {
                color: #ffffff;
                font-size: 20px;
                padding: 6px 0 4px;
                text-align: center;
                display: inline-block;
                width: 14.28%;
                border-right: 2px solid white;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                font-family: 'OpenSans_SemiBold';
            }
```

...and

```
.a4 .menu-item {
        width: 14.28%;
        float: left;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
```

So I thought menus and day-fields would be aligned correctly. But sadly, as seen in the fiddle, the nearer my plan goes "to sunday", the less space is between the menu and the end of the day-rectangle.

I hope someone here could help me out, because after trying to change position: relative to absolute and some other Ideas I am out of Ideas now and clearly in need of help.

**edit:** here's a screenshot from the comments better describing my problem! actually, I want all fields to look like the "Monday" with the same margin between pictures and end of "monday"-headline (sry for my bad english):

[image]

Comment: Why not use tables for the entire structure instead of splitting things up in divisions? You would then be able to keep your columns aligned correctly.

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean? Could you send a screen shot of what you are talking about. Because your fiddle looks good to me.

Comment: @kingkapd http://cjo.me/beraBYWMUo.png

Comment: so you want a bigger margin between Sunday and the border?

Comment: Is the screenshot you provided showing the problem? Or is what you want to achieve? What browser are you using?

Comment: Yeh it doesn't look the same in the fiddle ;)

Comment: Thanks to all of you! Just been on the toil... nevermind. Yes, the screenshot shows EXACTLY what i mean. the problem seems not to be the sunday-only, there is a small change in margins between monday and sunday, and I don'T know where it's coming from.

Comment: i use chrome here, latest version. Firefox and IE11 too, happens in every browser ;)

Comment: If I understood correctly, your problem is with menu items bellow days? they are "escaping" days which are above them? if this is the case, error is in colspan for .content, it's set to 2 and that makes .content larger (width) then days width, so 14.28% is not the same. Set colspan to 1 for .content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On this line remove colspan="2"

```
<tr class="content">
    <td class="hspace border-color">              
        <td class="border-color" colspan="2"> <--- here
```

And the reason is your table rows are of different width, the "days" row is 1174px and the "content" row is 1204px, so 14.28% of that width gives two different values

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your problem correctly but i think this might help.

http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/CSS3/Selectors/current/html/static/flat/css3-modsel-33.html

Use the last class to target the Sunday and give it a bigger margin? If that is what you want.

I hope this helps!

Comment: sorry for my somewhat late response. See the comments on the question please :) I don't quite think it's enough, but i'll give it a try!